# Why I'm not able to export this moongose Class?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ecmascript-6, export

Here's my User class/schema:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

let UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    enabled: {
        type: Boolean
    }
}, {
    collection: 'Users'
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
export default User
```

I'm doing `import` feature, so on another file (i.e. routes/account.js) I've:

```
import User from "../models/User";
```

but when I start the nodejs project, it says:

```
node:internal/errors:464
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\repos\Web\MyApp\backend\models\User' imported from C:\repos\Web\MyApp\backend\routes\account.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:418:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:981:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1078:11)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:530:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:251:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:79:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:78:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
Program node index.js exited with code 1
```

What's wrong?

Data structure:

[image]

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "MyApp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "supervisor index.js"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.27.2",
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "crypto": "^1.0.1",
        "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
        "crypto.js": "^3.0.0",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
        "express": "^4.18.1",
        "http-errors": "^2.0.0",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "moment": "^2.29.3",
        "mongoose": "^6.4.0",
        "supervisor": "^0.12.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Could You please add link to the repo ?

Comment: don't have any repo at the moment, local testing/trying the framework :(

Comment: Okay So please add folder & file structure, `pacakge.json` and rest of the files ... as much as You can ! ;-)

Comment: @MarioG8 did it now :) I've also added where I import it (i.e. routes/account.js)

Comment: I think You miss some extensions in Your code... When we use `import` we have to add extension to file ! In Your case like this =>  `import User from "../models/User.js"`;

Comment: Glad I could help You ! ;-) I posted my answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we use `import` ,we have to use **extension** like this:

```
import User from "../models/User.js";
                                 ^^
```